# Consistently Determine @useraccount from Default and Quoted Retweets

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm building a php cli script to retrieve tweets from a known list of users to determine if they retweeted tweets from a single @useraccount. Using the `user_timeline` api accessor I have determined that there are two types of retweets, default and quoted.

A default retweet has these attributes:

```
$result[0]->text: "RT @useraccount"

$result[0]->retweeted_status: "Some cool text goes here..."
```

But a quoted retweet has these attributes:

```
$result[0]->text: "Gonna be wicked awesome ya'll <shortened twitter url>"

$result[0]->quoted_status = "This epic fundraising event happens every year!"
```

As you can see, it's easy to extrapolate the @useraccount from a default retweet as it's directly referenced. But in a quoted retweet there is no mention of @useraccount anywhere in the text, or it's attributes.

Here is the post params I am using:

```
$result = $twitterOAuth->get('statuses/user_timeline', ['exclude_replies' => true, 'screen_name' => $username, 'trim_user' => true]);
```

Has anyone encountered this before? And if so what was your solution?